# Type 'Post' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

Tags: codable

```
import Foundation

struct PostsModel: Codable {
    let posts: [Post]
}

struct Post: Codable {
    let postID, timeshamp, likesCount: Int
    let title, previewText: String

    var timestampValue: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case timeshamp, title
        case postID = "postId"
        case previewText = "preview_text"
        case likesCount = "likes_count"
    }
```

> Type 'Post' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Variable name in CodingKeys are not the same as in Post struct.

For an example, use:

```
case likesCount = "likesCount"
```